# 401 Unauthorized for accessing customer api

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, api, rest-api

I was able to get the admin token using the below url against the created admin user
http://username:password@localhost.com/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token

The username and password is for browser authentication which you can see before the url which is defined in .htaccess and .htpassword. The original username and password is given in the body

```
{
"username":"admin",
"password":"admin123"
}
```

But when I get customers by passing the token it says 401 unauthorized.
Below is the request

http://username:password@localhost.com/index.php/rest/V1/customers
and token is passed as "Authorization: Bearer abcdefghi" in request header

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In magento web-API when you pass user name and password then it genrates token for that specific customer (Which is only valid for 1 hour - configurable from admin)

> http://magento.host/index.php/rest/V1/integration/customer/token?username=test.user@test.com&password=test@123

**webapi.xml code**

```
<route url="/V1/customers/me" method="GET">
    <service class="Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface" method="getById"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="self"/>
    </resources>
    <data>
        <parameter name="customerId" force="true">%customer_id%</parameter>
    </data>
</route>
```

**which returns token.**

After genrating token, when we pass that token in header.

```
Authorization :: Bearer <Token Value>

http://magento.host/index.php/rest/V1/customers/me
```

Which returns customer detailes.

The above case i explained is working fine for webAPI in magento2 which i tested in **POSTMAN**.

Comment: And yeah your URL action should be "POST"

Comment: I have created one admin user and new role with which will be "web api role" with access rights to customers and categories.  I have assigned the "web api role" to admin user. It means that this admin user can only access the customers and categories. Now I have successfully generate the token. But when I use that token to fetch the customers. It says 401 unauthorized. I have gone some many resources, I understand the concept but don't know why it is keep on giving 401 unauthorized

Comment: Okay, just for testing purpose please give all access role to that user and check whether it's giving a same error.

Comment: and did you checked the action of the URL ?

Comment: It was "GET" before now it is "POST" and still 401. Let me try be giving all access roles

Comment: yeah, let me know

Comment: it is still giving 401 unauthorized

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77790/discussion-between-aditya-shah-and-jn-newbie).

Answer (score 0):

Please pass username and password correctly

for customers API:
rest/V1/customer/token

Comment: Actually the username and password before url is for browser authentication which is defined in .htaccess. The original admin username and password was provided in body to get the token. Now to fetch the customers I think we will pass that token in header and simple call the url.

Comment: There is one more thing I have created this new admin api user in production mode with specific role to access customers and categories. Do I need to do something to reflect the change?